# Corba marshalling and proxy using writeReplace

Tags: java, serialization, proxy, corba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any equivalent to writeReplace in CORBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252304/is-there-any-equivalent-to-writereplace-in-corba)

I have in some part of my JavaEE application an homemade persistence component that returns collections and maps proxies. This component is used by my EJBs, which are accessed through web-services.

Unfortunatly, when using a lazy-loaded map or collection, it seems the EJB return value (which usually is my component return value) can't be serialized by the CORBA implementation used by Glassfish. indeed, each time I try to call such a methodj, I get a

```
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: ATTENTION: IOP00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy217.valuehandlerReadException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1022)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2162)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2404)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1224)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:935)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:928)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:918)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputObject.java:557)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:391)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectOverride(IIOPInputStream.java:544)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.LinkedList.readObject(LinkedList.java:964)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1832)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2162)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2404)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1224)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:935)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:928)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:918)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputObject.java:557)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:391)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectOverride(IIOPInputStream.java:544)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.LinkedList.readObject(LinkedList.java:964)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1832)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:935)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:525)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.copyobject.ORBStreamObjectCopierImpl.copy(ORBStreamObjectCopierImpl.java:78)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.copyobject.ORBStreamObjectCopierImpl.copy(ORBStreamObjectCopierImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.copyobject.FallbackObjectCopierImpl.copy(FallbackObjectCopierImpl.java:69)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.copyobject.FallbackObjectCopierImpl.copy(FallbackObjectCopierImpl.java:59)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.copyObject(Util.java:771)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.copyResult(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:473)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:243)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:262)
    at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:137)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.Utility.readAbstractAndNarrow(Utility.java:1028)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2157)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2404)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1224)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    ... 130 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.Object
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:245)
    ... 139 more
```

I tried implementing [`writeReplace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) method in my proxies,n but with no visible result.

So, what can I do to have my proxies serializing by loading their values and returning them ?

Comment: `writeReplace()` doesn't apply to CORBA marshalling. Is the problem class mentioned in, or reachable from, the remote interface?

Answer (score 0):

Someone tries to use a Java HashMap as CORBA Object which won't work. (See last exception). To provide a solution to your problem, please provide more information (code).