# Is there any equivalent to writeReplace in CORBA?

Tags: java, serialization, corba

When using standard Java serialization, it is possible to have an object replaced on the fly in stream by, according to [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface, creating a `Object writeReplace()` method that will be invoked during serialization.

My question is simple : is there an equivalent for this construct in Corba Java implementation ?

Comment: My question would be: What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `writeReplace` as normal with RMI-IIOP (Java RMI over CORBA/IIOP).  The ORB presents "standard" Java serialization of Serializable/Externalizable (with all associated features) and marshals them as "custom marshalled" values.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there isn't even such a thing in the Corba specification, let alone the Java implementation.